# Where to report bugs and request new feature for the new Stack Overflow apps? (do not confuse with SE app)

Tags: support, site-recommendation, mobile-app

Where should I submit bug reports and feature requests for the [new Stack Overflow app](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/05/16/stack-overflow-official-app-launches-ios-android) (android and iOS) and which tags should I use?

Comment: Close voters: this is a valid site recommendation question, like any other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the announcement on [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349255/stack-overflow-now-has-its-own-app-on-ios-and-android?cb=1) I learned they take them on [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com)

> Feedback on the existing Stack Exchange apps should continue to live on MSE. But, please report bugs and request features for the new Stack Overflow apps here on MSO:
>
> - [Give Android feedback](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-app)
> - [Give iOS feedback](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios-app).

I did create a tag wiki on Meta Stack Overflow for the [stackoverflow-app](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stackoverflow-app) but that seems to be overkill, if not wrong. The team prefers to use the existing `[android-app]` and `[ios-app]` tags on MSO to handle those.